# Cant scroll down to see footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a (Dutch) first year student studying ICT&Media Design and we are working with HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

While creating a page for myself to work with javascript, html and css I stumbled upon some problems.

I can't scroll down to see my footer on the page's. 
I'm pretty sure im doing something wrong with the fixed position but i can't seem to find out what exactly.

Hope you guys can help me, there's probably more wrong positioning wise.

Thank you in advance.

http://athena.fhict.nl/users/i299291/WP21/index.html
(School's Server)

Comment: Please post code that shows the issue - also you have 404s on some fonts

Comment: because you have all your main elements using either fixed or absolute positioning these take the elements out of the regular flow of the page, so the page basically has no height so there is nothing to scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your footer is not appearing because you are using unnecessary  using position. Remove all of your `position:fixed`  and `position:absolute` from your CSS and then page will scrollable and you can see your footer.

Here is the updated CSS; you can see all position are commented, no need to use them.

```
#header {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    position: relative; /* remove this line*/
    width: 100%;
}

#menubar {
    background-color: #2C2C2D;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    height: 51px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 261px auto 0; /* remove this line*/
    position: absolute; /* remove this line*/
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 1280px;
}
#containerIndex {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 530px;
    margin-top: 330px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: fixed; /* remove this line*/
    width: 1280px;
}
#footer {
    background-color: #C6C7C0;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    height: 48px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 880px auto 10px;/* remove this line*/
    position: fixed;/* remove this line*/
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 1280px;
}
```

Comment: Okay great, looking better. But as you can see on the page now, the changing header image is messed up. :(

Comment: you have to use a responsive image for header section then the layout will look perfect.

Comment: Done this, but as you can see now on the index page, if you scale it the picture doesn't stay in place. I tried fixing it but it hasn't worked for me yet.

Comment: Okay to fix the problem you have to use CSS media queries which will take care of the layout if the screen resolution changes. Also in your CSS you are using width `1280px`. Instead of using `px value` you must use `percentage` values. If this help then please close this question by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your footer has a fixed position. It is displaying behind your content. Get rid of that, and you should be able to scroll down to your footer.